# How to append script tag/JS to textarea as text (non executeable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, textarea

How would I go about printing out html tags / javascript as text in a textarea? (non-executeable)

I tried appending the JS/script tags, but that doesn't seem to append as text (= doesn't show anything in the textarea)

Jquery

```
  $('#textarea').append('' +
    '<script type="text/javascript">' +
        'adf.Params.PageName = encodeURIComponent("[hello]");' +
        'adf.Params.Divider = encodeURIComponent("|");' +
    '</script>' +
  '');
```

HTML

```
<textarea rows="12" cols="50" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/aw0pu6g1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be having an issue related to the script tags.  One option is to encode the `<` character on the open and close script tags so that they will not be evaluated as actual tags.

```js
var text = '&lt;script type="text/javascript">\n\t' +
  'adf.Params.PageName = encodeURIComponent("[hello]");\n\t' +
  'adf.Params.Divider = encodeURIComponent("|");\n' +
  '&lt;/script>';

$('#textarea').append(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="12" cols="50" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Cheers taplar - it works! Do you know if there's any way to make to print out formatted with link breaks, tabbed etc.? (so it looks "pretty")

Comment: @user1231561 You can add `\n` for new lines and `\t` for tabs.  Updated answer.

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm - appreciate the nice effort Taplar